# Getting errors when using the grammar environment before \chapter{} and \begin{description}

Tags: environments, acronyms

I hope you can help me.

I am using an empty `grammar` environment, included in the `syntax` package, within a file called `appendix_c.tex`, whose contents are as follows:

```
\chapter{Modified version of the grammar of VHDL}\label{short-vhdl-grammar}

\begin{grammar}
\end{grammar}
```

Then, in a file called `acronyms.tex` I inserted the following code:

```
\chapter{List of acronyms}

\begin{description}
\item[ASIC] Application-Specific Integrated Circuit

\item[CORBA] Common Object Request Broker Architecture

\item[DCS] Digital Communications System
\item[DSML] Domain-Specific Modeling Language
...
\end{description}
```

I was using `acronym` instead of `description`, but got the same problem. I get the following error every time I process the main file `thesis.tex`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.11 \begin{description}
```

And the contents of `thesis.tex` are roughly like this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{captcont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hang]{subfigure}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nounderscore]{syntax}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\linespread{1.3}

% Top margin
\setlength{\voffset}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
% Heading space
\setlength{\headheight}{13pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
% Left side margin
\setlength{\hoffset}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}
% Text dimensions
\setlength{\textheight}{596pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6in}
% Page number space
\setlength{\footskip}{27.10125pt}
% Margin notes
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{headings}

...

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgments}

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{./chapter_1/chapter_1}
\include{./chapter_2/chapter_2}
\include{./chapter_3/chapter_3}
\include{./chapter_4/chapter_4}
\include{./chapter_5/chapter_5}
\include{./chapter_6/chapter_6}
\include{./chapter_7/chapter_7}

\appendix

\include{./appendix_a/appendix_a}
\include{./appendix_b/appendix_b}
\include{./appendix_c/appendix_c}
\include{./acronyms/acronyms}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibliography}{}

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be located in the transition from `appendix_c.tex` and `acronyms.tex`. Does anybody know what is going on? I cannot even start to type any grammar because of this problem. And I tried getting rid of the `acronym` environment but the issue is still present.

Comment: Did you try using it in the main document without any `include` with some dummy text? You can start reducing your example by stripping out the details and isolating the real cause. The problem looks like a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  Personally, I have often solved my own problems in the process of reducing the amount of code actually required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I did attempt to reduce your code to a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) but was not able to get it to a point where I could reproduce the problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I remove the use of the grammar environment from appendix_c.tex everything works fine.

Comment: Why have an empty `grammar` environment in the first place?

Answer (score 6):

Do not leave the `grammar` environment empty; it is built using a `list`, so leaving it without contents (in the presence of another list-like environment!) will trigger the error. This minimal example reproduces the error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
\end{grammar}

\begin{description}
\item[a]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

You can comment out the lines beginning and ending the environment:

```
%\begin{grammar}
%\end{grammar}
```

or, if for some reason you need the environment there without the actual contents, simply populate it with something it expects:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}

\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident> ‘=’ <expr>
\end{grammar}

\begin{description}
\item[a]
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

you can also use something simpler such as

```
\begin{grammar}
\item a
\end{grammar}
```